# Cloud Haskell query

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to execute the code on

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-simplelocalnet-0.2.3.3/docs/Control-Distributed-Process-Backend-SimpleLocalnet.html

I get the following error

```
$ ghc -threaded Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:4:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Control.Distributed.Process.Backend.SimpleLocalnet’
```

I reinstalled the `cloud-haskell` and `distributed-process` package using cabal, still I got the same error. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I am using Ubuntu(latest version).

Thanks

Comment: Since `Control.Distributed.Process.Backend.SimpleLocalnet` comes from `distributed-process-simplelocalnet`, you should install that...

Comment: are you using `stack` or `cabal`? - you write about cabal, but you added the tag `haskell-stack`? did you `cabal install distributed-process-simplelocalnet` ? which `ghc` and `cabal` version are you using? can you add the output of `ghc-pkg list`?

Comment: The package had been already installed. Guess it must have been broken. So I did a force reinstall and everything is working like a charm. Thank you so much Alec.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I used cabal, and the answer by Alec worked. Thanks a lot !!